# Custom dict class, assigning to deeper levels

Tags: python

I'v been struggle for days trying to make this custom dict class work. Until now it's working great for one level deep assignments, more than that it gets updated but won't trigger the class `__setitem__`

**config.yml:**

```yaml
Hello: Coders
deepfoo:
  bar: This is yaml
```

**main.py:**

```py
class Config(dict):
    def __init__(self, file_path='config.yml'):
        self._file_path = file_path
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            self.update(yaml.safe_load(f))
    
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        super().__setitem__(k, v)
        with open(self._file_path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(yaml.dump(dict(self), sort_keys=False))

CONFIG = Config()
CONFIG['Hello'] = "World"
CONFIG['deepfoo']['bar'] = "This is a Test"
print(CONFIG)
```

**Output**

```
(env) user:~$ python3 config.py 
{'Hello': 'World', 'deepfoo': {'bar': 'This is a Test'}}
```

The output prints the expected dictionary output, but the yml file only gets updated with the one level deep assignment.

**config.yml** after code run:

```yaml
Hello: World
deepfoo:
  bar: This is yaml
```

Expected **config.yml**:

```yaml
Hello: World
deepfoo:
  bar: This is a Test
```

Comment: What is expected content of **config.yml**?

Comment: @Daweo just fixed the post

Answer (score 0):

After you retrieve an element from the object (`CONFIG['Hello']` for example), the object has no relation or control over it whatsoever.

```
#this line
CONFIG['deepfoo']['bar'] = "This is a Test"
#is equivalent to
unrelated = CONFIG['deepfoo']
unrelated['bar'] = "This is a Test"
```

While the content of mutable elements inside the `CONFIG` can change, the `__setitem__` does not get called. You'll have to wrap all its changeable child elements in some kind of proxy, if you really want to go this way. The simplest example would be something like this:

```
def _need_wrap(value,parent):
    return hasattr(value,'__getitem__') and not (isinstance(value,Element) and value.parent==parent)
class Config(dict):
    def _write(self):
        with open(self._file_path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(yaml.dump(dict(self), sort_keys=False))
    def __init__(self, file_path='config.yml'):
        self._file_path = file_path
        with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
            self.update(yaml.safe_load(f))  
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        super().__setitem__(k, v)
        self._write()   
    def __getitem__(self,k):
        v = super().__getitem__(k)
        if _need_wrap(v,self):
            return Element(v,self)
        return v
class Element:
    def __init__(self,value,parent):
        self._parent = parent
        self._value = value
    def __getitem__(self,k):
        v = self._value[k]
        if _need_wrap(v,self._parent):
            return Element(v,self._parent)
        return v
    def __setitem__(self,k,v):
        self._value[k] = v
        self._parent._write()
    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return yaml.dump(node._value,sort_keys=False)
```

However, for all but the simplest cases this opens the can of worms you'd better keep tightly closed. Like what happens on copy, how to handle the value's other `__methods__` and so on.

Are you sure you don't want to simply do your stuff and then write the final version of the file?